# TextView go to new line in space

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with a text composed of two words, where the second is dynamic (like "Number of device: xxxxxxxxxxxx". I want that if the String is too long, it will display like

```
Number of device:
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now it is like

```
Number of device: xxxxxxx
xxx
```

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/ObuTransitElementObuDeviceCode"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/empty_text_placeholder"
                android:breakStrategy="balanced"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
```

Comment: Can you please post your textview code in your question?

Comment: \r\n on setText()

Comment: @javdromero doesn't this make 2 lines every time? i want that it create 2 lines only when all the text doesn't fit in one line

Comment: Do you have an implemented setText? Can you show that?

Comment: You can use 'maxLines' attribute

Comment: I tried your code and there's no need for `breakStrategy` . It would automatically wrap the whole word to new line if there's a space after the (:) sign and after that it's a whole word `tv.setText("Number of device: 12354546151115151");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to observe layout changes in this case since the due to height change the bottom value will be changed if the text set to two line.

**work with wrap_content only**

```
TextView tvDevice = findViewById(R.id.ObuTransitElementObuDeviceCode);
tvDevice.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if(bottom != oldBottom){
                    String s = tvDevice.getText().toString();
                    if(!s.contains("\n"))tvDevice.setText(s.replace(":",":\n"));
                }
            }
        });
tvDevice.setText("Number of device:\n"+dynamic_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

just do :

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.ObuTransitElementObuDeviceCode);
tv.setText("Number of device:\n"+dynamic_number);
```